# How do I expand the quick open search box in the VS Code Command Center?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I make heavy use of the workbench toolbar to know which file I am currently on.
Unfortunately VS Code crops the end of the path.
Any way to make it full-width ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From googling: "`site:github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues command center width`": [Allow adjusting search text box width in title bar to accommodate long path and file names. #174616](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/174616). I.e. It's not supported right now. Give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it, and subscribe to it to get notified of discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like "+1" / "bump" / "me too".